# how to inject a logger instance using MEF?

Tags: c#, mef

Is it possible to inject an instance of logger class object using Managed Extensibility Framework? Please show a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using **Constructor Injection**:

```
private readonly ILogger logger;

[ImportingConstructor]
public MyClass(ILogger logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

Obviously (if you know MEF) some other type must **Export** `ILogger`...

Alternatively, you can also use **Property Injection**, although I find the semantics vague:

```
[Import(typeof(ILogger))]
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```